# Unsubscribe when subscribed subject completes

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have a subject that subscribes to an event listener Observable (`fromEvent`). When the button stop is clicked, the subject completes and the event listener should be removed. Currently, I'm keeping track of the subscription and unsubscribe it, which also removes the event listener:

```js
const { fromEvent, Subject } = rxjs
const { map } = rxjs.operators

const subject = new Subject()

subject.subscribe(() => console.log('focused'))

const sub = fromEvent(document.querySelector('input'), 'focus').subscribe(subject)

document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
  // This is what I would like to avoid
  sub.unsubscribe;
  subject.complete();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<input>
<button>Stop</button>
```

Is it possible to automatically unsubscribe the subscription `sub` (and remove the event listener) when `subject` completes? Something like `takeUntilComplete(subject)` without installing an additional library.

Edit: The example here is oversimplified. In my real scenario, there is no button that lets the subject complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider extending `Subject` class to notify its unsubscribe/error/complete as below:

```js
class NotifyStateSubject<T> extends Subject<T>{
  public stopped = new Subject<void>();

  private notify(): void {
    this.stopped.next();
    this.stopped.unsubscribe();
  }

  public error(err: any):void {
    this.notify();
    super.error(err)
  }

  public complete():void{
    this.notify();
    super.complete()
  }

 public unsubscribe():void {
    this.notify();
    super.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

then use it as following:

```
fromEvent(...).pipe(takeUntil(subject.stopped$)).subscribe(subject)
```

Comment: Interesting solution! Thanks for your answer. In the meantime, I found a different solution which I added for completeness (no pun intended ;-)). Nothing is as elegant as having a `takeUntilComplete` operator. ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

you're over thinking this a bit, this is all you need:

```
const stop$ = fromEvent(document.querySelector('button'), 'click');

fromEvent(document.querySelector('input'), 'focus').pipe(takeUntil(stop$)).subscribe(subject)
```

the completion from the `takeUntil` will propagate down to the subscribed subject.  All subscriptions and event listeners will end with a button click.

The only thing that WONT happen, is if the Subject completes some way OTHER than button click, then your input event will still fire, though the subscriber won't be listening anymore. Completion propagates downstream but not upstream.

Alternatively creating new operators is pretty easy (riffing off your solution):

```
const takeUntilComplete = (subject) => 
  takeUntil(new Observable(o => 
    subject.subscribe(null, null, () => o.next())))
```

which can be used as simply as:

```
fromEvent(document.querySelector('input'), 'focus').pipe(takeUntilComplete(subject)).subscribe(subject)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to choose a very simple example, but I might have oversimplified things too much. In my real use case, I do not have a button that is clicked; the subscription completes in a different, much more complex way. Sorry for not making that clear in my question. I will edit it.

Comment: alrighty, well i added how you could make an operator of your own

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant, but creating a new Observable which emits on complete of the subject works:

```
fromEvent(...).pipe(
  takeUntil(
    new Observable((subscriber) =>
      this._trackedInteractions$?.subscribe({ complete: () => subscriber.next() })
    )
  )
).subscribe(subject)
```